# Не срабатывает ивент OnTriggerEnter2D

Tags: c#, unity3d, visual-studio, button, ui

Делаю код для игры и задал специальные параметры в меню все работает на ура а вот сам игрок когда попадает на Collider2D не переходит на следующий уровень.Помогите решить проблему заранее спасибо!

код с которым неполадки

```
public int NewLevel;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

}
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D col2D)
{
    if (col2D.tag == "Player") {
        //Application.LoadLevel (0);
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt ("level", NewLevel);
    }
}
```

работающий код чтобы была понятна суть скриптов

```
private int LevelOpen;

public Button Level2;
public int Level_Load;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    LevelOpen = PlayerPrefs.GetInt ("level");
    if (LevelOpen == 2) {
        Level2.interactable = true;
    }
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

}
public void OnLoad()
{
    SceneManager.LoadScene (Level_Load);
}
```

Comment: Потому, что коллайд происходит только если движется тело, а не через transform.

Comment: Непонятно если честно кто на чем стоит. Варианта бага два, первый не срабатывает коллайдер (можно поставить: "Debug.LogWarning("Contact") и посмотреть пишет ли оно в лог (ну или просто бряк поставить). Второй нюанс, в этом коде мы просто сетим в PlayerPrefs значение. А есть код который проверяет что оно изменилось, и что надо загружать уровень?

Comment: Помимо вышеизложенного, убедитесь, что у Игрока проставлен тег, который Вы проверяете.

Comment: Александр, я тег поставил давно и сразу после написания кода